# Exporting a MySQL database through PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, database, export, phpmyadmin

I'm hoping to export a database that I only have access to through phpMyAdmin so that I can make a copy of it on my localhost.  I've never done this before and the database is fairly large at 200 tables.  Does anyone have experience doing this?  I'm just unsure if the web interface of phpMyAdmin is a reliable way to export that much data or if I'd be causing some performance issues by attempting to export the data.

Thanks for any advice. Thy phpMyAdmin version is 2.1 if that helps any.

Comment: Did you at least try it?

Comment: 200 tables is not a problem. The amount of data might be, but that could be a problem with a single table as well.

Answer (score 4):

In the table, select Export, tick the "Save as file" option, and keep the selection as "Compression: None".

You will be able to download huge data tables like this.

Comment: Yes. My export was silently failing part way through (failing when hitting binary data in BLOB fields I think) I had been assuming that setting compression to 'gzipped' was sensible, but after a long process of trial and error I've found that my whole database exports correctly if compression is set to none. The fact that an export can fail silently like this, is worrying. Perhaps the real answer to this question is "No it's not reliable"!

Answer (score 2):

The issue you will come against is the `max_execution_time` setting.

What i have found is large databases take longer to dump than what is set here (defaults to 30 seconds).

This will cause your export to fail.

Also make sure you are not trying to dump to the browser, I have found that option unreliable. Choose the save to a file option, and download the dump via ftp .

But as Col. Shrapnel said, try it first!